# Asp.net Core/ODATA Controller not receiving the id when sent from Postman

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, odata

I am exploring OData.

I have been following [Working with OData - Integrating an Existing ASP.NET Core 3.x API](https://referbruv.com/blog/posts/working-with-odata-integrating-an-existing-aspnet-core-3x-api) by Referbruv!

My EdmModel follows his and is as follows:

```
    internal static IEdmModel GetEdmModel() {
        // create OData builder instance
        var builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();

        // CLIENTS
        // map the entities set which are the types returned from the endpoint onto the OData pipeline
        // the string parameter is the name of the controller 
        // which supplies the data of type Client entity model in this case
        builder.EntitySet<ClientIndexDto>("ODataClient").EntityType.HasKey(x => x.id);
        builder.EntitySet<ClientDetailsDto>("ODataClientDetails").EntityType.HasKey(x => x.id);


        // configure a function onto the builder, AllClients 
        // which is same as the name provided in the ODataRoute
        builder.Function("AllClients")
            .ReturnsCollectionFromEntitySet<ClientIndexDto>("ODataClient");

        builder.Function("ClientById")
            .ReturnsCollectionFromEntitySet<ClientDetailsDto>("ODataClientDetails")
            .Parameter<int>("id");


        return builder.GetEdmModel();
    }
```

The section:

```
builder.Function("ClientById")
            .ReturnsCollectionFromEntitySet<ClientDetailsDto>("ODataClientDetails")
            .Parameter<int>("id");
```

Deals with getting a client by Id.

For completeness I have in My StartUp.cs file the following for OData:

```
        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => { 
            endpoints.MapControllers();
            endpoints.Select().Filter().OrderBy().Expand().Count().MaxTop(10);
            endpoints.MapODataRoute("odata", "odata", GetEdmModel());
        });
```

The $metadata returned is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<edmx:Edmx Version="4.0" xmlns:edmx="http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/ns/edmx">
    <edmx:DataServices>
        <Schema Namespace="JobsLedger.MODELS.API.App.Client" xmlns="http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/ns/edm">
            <EntityType Name="ClientIndexDto">
                <Key>
                    <PropertyRef Name="id" />
                </Key>
                <Property Name="id" Type="Edm.Int32" Nullable="false" />
                <Property Name="ClientNo" Type="Edm.String" />
                <Property Name="Active" Type="Edm.Boolean" Nullable="false" />
                <Property Name="ClientFirstName" Type="Edm.String" />
                <Property Name="ClientLastName" Type="Edm.String" />
                <Property Name="Company" Type="Edm.Boolean" Nullable="false" />
                <Property Name="CompanyName" Type="Edm.String" />
                <Property Name="MobilePhone" Type="Edm.String" />
                <Property Name="IsWarrantyCompany" Type="Edm.Boolean" Nullable="false" />
                <Property Name="JobsCount" Type="Edm.String" />
            </EntityType>
            <EntityType Name="ClientDetailsDto">
                <Key>
                    <PropertyRef Name="id" />
                </Key>
                <Property Name="id" Type="Edm.Int32" Nullable="false" />
                <Property Name="ClientNo" Type="Edm.String" />
                <Property Name="Company" Type="Edm.Boolean" Nullable="false" />
                <Property Name="IsWarrantyCompany" Type="Edm.Boolean" Nullable="false" />
                <Property Name="CompanyName" Type="Edm.String" />
                <Property Name="ClientFirstName" Type="Edm.String" />
                <Property Name="ClientLastName" Type="Edm.String" />
                <Property Name="MobilePhone" Type="Edm.String" />
                <Property Name="DeActivated" Type="Edm.String" />
                <Property Name="CreatedOn" Type="Edm.String" />
                <Property Name="CreatedBy" Type="Edm.String" />
                <Property Name="ModifiedOn" Type="Edm.String" />
                <Property Name="ModifiedBy" Type="Edm.String" />
                <Property Name="SuburbId" Type="Edm.Int32" Nullable="false" />
                <NavigationProperty Name="Address" Type="JobsLedger.MODELS.Common.Address.AddressDto" />
                <NavigationProperty Name="ClientJobs" Type="Collection(JobsLedger.MODELS.API.App.Job.ClientJobDto)" />
                <NavigationProperty Name="ClientNotes" Type="Collection(JobsLedger.MODELS.Common.Notes.ClientNoteDto)" />
            </EntityType>
        </Schema>
        <Schema Namespace="JobsLedger.MODELS.Common.Address" xmlns="http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/ns/edm">
            <EntityType Name="AddressDto">
                <Key>
                    <PropertyRef Name="Address1" />
                </Key>
                <Property Name="Address1" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="false" />
                <Property Name="Address2" Type="Edm.String" />
                <Property Name="SuburbId" Type="Edm.Int32" Nullable="false" />
                <Property Name="SuburbName" Type="Edm.String" />
                <Property Name="StateShortName" Type="Edm.String" />
                <Property Name="Postcode" Type="Edm.String" />
            </EntityType>
        </Schema>
        <Schema Namespace="JobsLedger.MODELS.API.App.Job" xmlns="http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/ns/edm">
            <EntityType Name="ClientJobDto">
                <Key>
                    <PropertyRef Name="Id" />
                </Key>
                <Property Name="Id" Type="Edm.Int32" Nullable="false" />
                <Property Name="JobNo" Type="Edm.String" />
                <Property Name="AgentJobNo" Type="Edm.String" />
                <Property Name="Type" Type="Edm.String" />
                <Property Name="Status" Type="Edm.String" />
                <Property Name="WarrantyCompany" Type="Edm.String" />
                <Property Name="NumberOfVisits" Type="Edm.String" />
                <Property Name="CreatedOn" Type="Edm.String" />
                <Property Name="CreatedBy" Type="Edm.String" />
                <Property Name="ModifiedOn" Type="Edm.String" />
                <Property Name="ModifiedBy" Type="Edm.String" />
                <NavigationProperty Name="JobNotes" Type="Collection(JobsLedger.MODELS.Common.Notes.JobNoteDto)" />
                <NavigationProperty Name="JobVisits" Type="Collection(JobsLedger.MODELS.API.App.Job.JobVisitDto)" />
            </EntityType>
            <EntityType Name="JobVisitDto">
                <Key>
                    <PropertyRef Name="Id" />
                </Key>
                <Property Name="Id" Type="Edm.Int32" Nullable="false" />
                <Property Name="DateCreated" Type="Edm.String" />
                <Property Name="VisitDate" Type="Edm.String" />
                <Property Name="StartTime" Type="Edm.String" />
                <Property Name="EndTime" Type="Edm.String" />
            </EntityType>
        </Schema>
        <Schema Namespace="JobsLedger.MODELS.Common.Notes" xmlns="http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/ns/edm">
            <EntityType Name="JobNoteDto">
                <Key>
                    <PropertyRef Name="Id" />
                </Key>
                <Property Name="Id" Type="Edm.Int32" Nullable="false" />
                <Property Name="JobId" Type="Edm.Int32" Nullable="false" />
                <Property Name="Details" Type="Edm.String" />
                <Property Name="NoteType" Type="Edm.String" />
                <Property Name="CreatedOnDate" Type="Edm.String" />
                <Property Name="CreatedOnTime" Type="Edm.String" />
                <Property Name="CreatedBy" Type="Edm.String" />
                <Property Name="ModifiedOnDate" Type="Edm.String" />
                <Property Name="ModifiedOnTime" Type="Edm.String" />
                <Property Name="ModifiedBy" Type="Edm.String" />
            </EntityType>
            <EntityType Name="ClientNoteDto">
                <Key>
                    <PropertyRef Name="id" />
                </Key>
                <Property Name="id" Type="Edm.Int32" Nullable="false" />
                <Property Name="Details" Type="Edm.String" />
                <Property Name="NoteType" Type="Edm.String" />
                <Property Name="CreatedOnDate" Type="Edm.String" />
                <Property Name="CreatedOnTime" Type="Edm.String" />
                <Property Name="CreatedBy" Type="Edm.String" />
                <Property Name="ModifiedOnDate" Type="Edm.String" />
                <Property Name="ModifiedOnTime" Type="Edm.String" />
                <Property Name="ModifiedBy" Type="Edm.String" />
            </EntityType>
        </Schema>
        <Schema Namespace="Default" xmlns="http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/ns/edm">
            <Function Name="AllClients">
                <ReturnType Type="Collection(JobsLedger.MODELS.API.App.Client.ClientIndexDto)" />
            </Function>
            <Function Name="ClientById">
                <Parameter Name="id" Type="Edm.Int32" Nullable="false" />
                <ReturnType Type="Collection(JobsLedger.MODELS.API.App.Client.ClientDetailsDto)" />
            </Function>
            <EntityContainer Name="Container">
                <EntitySet Name="ODataClient" EntityType="JobsLedger.MODELS.API.App.Client.ClientIndexDto" />
                <EntitySet Name="ODataClientDetails" EntityType="JobsLedger.MODELS.API.App.Client.ClientDetailsDto" />
                <FunctionImport Name="AllClients" Function="Default.AllClients" EntitySet="ODataClient" IncludeInServiceDocument="true" />
                <FunctionImport Name="ClientById" Function="Default.ClientById" EntitySet="ODataClientDetails" IncludeInServiceDocument="true" />
            </EntityContainer>
        </Schema>
    </edmx:DataServices>
</edmx:Edmx>
```

My Controller is as follows:

```
using JobsLedger.API.Controllers.API.App.Interfaces;
using JobsLedger.API.ControllerServices.API.App.ClientService.Interfaces;
using JobsLedger.DATA;
using JobsLedger.DATA.Repositories.Interfaces;
using JobsLedger.MODELS.API.App.Client;

using Microsoft.AspNet.OData;
using Microsoft.AspNet.OData.Routing;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using AutoMapper;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;

namespace JobsLedger.API.Controllers.API.App {

    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    [Authorize(Roles = "TenantAdmin,Admin,Employee")]
    public class ODataClientController : ODataController, IClientController {
        private readonly IClientServices _clientServices;

        public ODataClientController( IClientServices clientServices) {
            _clientServices = clientServices;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        [EnableQuery()]
        [ODataRoute("AllClients()")]
        public IActionResult Get() 
        {
            return Ok(_clientServices.GetAllClientsAsDto());
        }

        [HttpGet]
        [EnableQuery]
        [ODataRoute("ClientById(id={id})")]
        public IActionResult Get(int id) {
            return Ok(_clientServices.GetClient(id));
        }
```

I want to get a client with an ID of "5" so I use the following get command in Postman:

```
https://localhost:44301/odata/ClientById(id=5)?
```

This is as the tutorial indicates - with brackets around the "id=5"

It gets to the endpoint but the id is set to "0".

[image]

Given my EdmModel, the #MetaData, and the controller action for a single Id why, when I send a GET command with an `(Id=5)` I get an Id=0? What do I need to do to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

In the article comments, Referbruv also mentions issue with routing in .net core 3.1. So, you can try it in 3.0 and if it works there, it is the issue with 3.1.

If you can do it with *id=* then based on the [attr-routing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/odata/webapi/attribute-routing) this should work.

```
[ODataRoute("ClientById({id})")]
```

Comment: Getting a "404 Not Found" after changing to [ODataRoute("ClientById({id})")]. I used: https://localhost:44301/odata/ClientById(5) as my URI.. any ideas?

Comment: Try to remove apicontroller and route attribute from ODataClientController

Comment: Did as you suggested:  //[Route("api/[controller]")] //[ApiController] and got the 404 issue..

Comment: Can you please post your project to github or somewhere? Just these classes. Thanks

Comment: I've fixed it amazingly... When back to the original set up as above but changed the EdmModel function to this: var function = builder.Function("ClientById");
 function.Parameter<int>("id");
 function.ReturnsCollectionFromEntitySet<ClientDetailsDto>("ODataClientDetails");...... I think that moving the "function.Parameter<int>("id")" to before the returnsCollectionFromEntitySet made the difference.. Thank you for having a look.. I am very appreciative.